# wiringPi.h: No such file or directory #include < wiringPi.h>

Tags: wiringpi

When I try to compile I get this error:

```
fatal error: wiringPi.h: No such file or directory 
#include < wiringPi.h>
                      ^
```

[image]

The code is:

[image]

My includes are:

```c
#include < wiringPi.h>
#include < stdio.h>

#define LEDPIN 0
```

I have double and triple checked the spelling on everything, and WiringPi is installed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the space after the <.  The system is looking for a file called " wiringPi.h" rather than "wiringPi.h".

I.e. use

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

The space after < causes problem. 
`#include < wiringPi.h>` ==> Wrong
`#include <wiringPi.h>`  ==> Correct.
Some sample codes at various sites are having this typo error. :-)

Comment: This seems to be what [joan already suggested](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/80007/58316) in the accepted answer; is there anything new you can add to the answers?

Answer (score -1):

As the answer is already given I just want to share that you can use #include if you are using C++ (and not C). It will import all the libraries in the beginning. However, it will give increase the compilation time for the program.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/66581)

Comment: I wonder if I will be able to do it when I will get negative votes on my answers

Comment: I did not downvote; however not only is this not an answer to the question asked, it is incorrect and does not make any sense. If you want reputation you need to provide accurate well-researched answers.